# Install azure-storage in Docker

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-storage

I'm compiling some python code on a Docker file with some azure blob storage function (and therefore importing azure.storage.blob), but docker fails to install it. The line I'm using in the Dockerfile to install it is the following:

```
RUN pip3 install azure-storage
```

And this is the error it returns:

```
Step 2/5 : RUN pip3 install azure-storage
 ---> Running in c519b76cad94
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 384
Collecting azure-storage
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/26/482c033f8f3a48d16cf75aad91c3e1256856719f4117fabb4696d33aa5da/azure_storage-0.36.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (190kB)
Collecting azure-common>=1.1.5 (from azure-storage)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/f8/46248b201fd38b7e93c6da644e2fc3bc5a39118f253562751fd295a8cc77/azure_common-1.1.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting azure-nspkg>=2.0.0 (from azure-storage)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/0c/c562be95a9a2ed52454f598571cf300b1114d0db2aa27f5b8ed3bb9cd0c0/azure_nspkg-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from azure-storage)
Collecting cryptography (from azure-storage)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/ca/bc827c5e55918ad223d59d299fff92f3563476c3b00d0a9157d9c0217449/cryptography-2.6.1.tar.gz (491kB)
Collecting python-dateutil (from azure-storage)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (226kB)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from requests->azure-storage)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from requests->azure-storage)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from requests->azure-storage)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from requests->azure-storage)
Collecting asn1crypto>=0.21.0 (from cryptography->azure-storage)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/cd/35485615f45f30a510576f1a56d1e0a7ad7bd8ab5ed7cdc600ef7cd06222/asn1crypto-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (101kB)
Collecting cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 (from cryptography->azure-storage)
  Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/cffi/cffi-1.12.2-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv6l.whl (309kB)
Collecting six>=1.4.1 (from cryptography->azure-storage)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycparser (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography->azure-storage)
  Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/pycparser/pycparser-2.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: cryptography
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cryptography: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cryptography: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-l71r1ht3/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp5o257jp6pip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  qemu: Unsupported syscall: 384
  c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
   #include <ffi.h>
                   ^
  compilation terminated.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 118, in _compile
      extra_postargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 909, in spawn
      spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/spawn.py", line 36, in spawn
      _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/spawn.py", line 159, in _spawn_posix
      % (cmd, exit_status))
  distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 161, in run
      cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 147, in call_command
      self.run_command(cmdname)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 24, in run
      self.build()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 109, in build
      self.run_command('build_ext')
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 75, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 196, in build_extension
      _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 533, in build_extension
      depends=ext.depends)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
      self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 120, in _compile
      raise CompileError(msg)
  distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 157, in save_modules
      yield saved
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
      yield
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 255, in run_setup
      DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 285, in run
      return func()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 253, in runner
      _execfile(setup_script, ns)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
      exec(code, globals, locals)
    File "/tmp/easy_install-tmva8ubl/cffi-1.12.2/setup.py", line 248, in <module>
      name=about["__title__"],
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 163, in setup
      raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
  SystemExit: error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1131, in run_setup
      run_setup(setup_script, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 258, in run_setup
      raise
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
      self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
      yield
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
      self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 169, in save_modules
      saved_exc.resume()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 144, in resume
      six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
      raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 157, in save_modules
      yield saved
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
      yield
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 255, in run_setup
      DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 285, in run
      return func()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 253, in runner
      _execfile(setup_script, ns)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
      exec(code, globals, locals)
    File "/tmp/easy_install-tmva8ubl/cffi-1.12.2/setup.py", line 248, in <module>
      name=about["__title__"],
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 163, in setup
      raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
  SystemExit: error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-l71r1ht3/cryptography/setup.py", line 324, in <module>
      **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
      _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 317, in __init__
      self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 372, in fetch_build_eggs
      replace_conflicting=True,
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 846, in resolve
      dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1118, in best_match
      return self.obtain(req, installer)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1130, in obtain
      return installer(requirement)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 440, in fetch_build_egg
      return cmd.easy_install(req)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 699, in easy_install
      return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 725, in install_item
      dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 906, in install_eggs
      return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1145, in build_and_install
      self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1133, in run_setup
      raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
  distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cryptography
  Running setup.py clean for cryptography
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-l71r1ht3/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
  qemu: Unsupported syscall: 384
  c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
   #include <ffi.h>
                   ^
  compilation terminated.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 118, in _compile
      extra_postargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 909, in spawn
      spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/spawn.py", line 36, in spawn
      _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/spawn.py", line 159, in _spawn_posix
      % (cmd, exit_status))
  distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 161, in run
      cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 147, in call_command
      self.run_command(cmdname)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 24, in run
      self.build()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 109, in build
      self.run_command('build_ext')
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 75, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 196, in build_extension
      _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 533, in build_extension
      depends=ext.depends)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
      self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 120, in _compile
      raise CompileError(msg)
  distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 157, in save_modules
      yield saved
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
      yield
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 255, in run_setup
      DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 285, in run
      return func()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 253, in runner
      _execfile(setup_script, ns)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
      exec(code, globals, locals)
    File "/tmp/easy_install-tezomh9u/cffi-1.12.2/setup.py", line 248, in <module>
      name=about["__title__"],
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 163, in setup
      raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
  SystemExit: error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1131, in run_setup
      run_setup(setup_script, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 258, in run_setup
      raise
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
      self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
      yield
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
      self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 169, in save_modules
      saved_exc.resume()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 144, in resume
      six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
      raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 157, in save_modules
      yield saved
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
      yield
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 255, in run_setup
      DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 285, in run
      return func()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 253, in runner
      _execfile(setup_script, ns)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
      exec(code, globals, locals)
    File "/tmp/easy_install-tezomh9u/cffi-1.12.2/setup.py", line 248, in <module>
      name=about["__title__"],
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 163, in setup
      raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
  SystemExit: error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-l71r1ht3/cryptography/setup.py", line 324, in <module>
      **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
      _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 317, in __init__
      self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 372, in fetch_build_eggs
      replace_conflicting=True,
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 846, in resolve
      dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1118, in best_match
      return self.obtain(req, installer)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1130, in obtain
      return installer(requirement)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 440, in fetch_build_egg
      return cmd.easy_install(req)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 699, in easy_install
      return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 725, in install_item
      dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 906, in install_eggs
      return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1145, in build_and_install
      self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1133, in run_setup
      raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
  distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
Installing collected packages: azure-common, azure-nspkg, asn1crypto, pycparser, cffi, six, cryptography, python-dateutil, azure-storage
  Running setup.py install for cryptography: started
    Running setup.py install for cryptography: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-l71r1ht3/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-rtclcdv5-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    qemu: Unsupported syscall: 384
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-armv6l-3.5
    creating build/lib.linux-armv6l-3.5/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/__about__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv6l-3.5/cryptography

    [...]

    writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
    writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5/_padding.c'
    creating build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5/_constant_time.c'
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5/_openssl.c'
    building '_openssl' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5/build
    creating build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5/build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.5-6waWnr/python3.5-3.5.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5/build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5/_openssl.o -Wconversion -Wno-error=sign-conversion
    build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.5/_openssl.c:498:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
     #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
                                  ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-l71r1ht3/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-rtclcdv5-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-l71r1ht3/cryptography/
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install azure-storage' returned a non-zero code: 1
2019/02/28 16:04:23 Container failed during run: build. No retries remaining.
failed to run step ID: build: exit status 1

Run ID: cf2q failed after 3m13s
Run failed
```

I've tried changing *azure-storage* by *azure*, *azure-storage-blob*, etc. with the same result.

Any idea on what is the syntax to install azure functions on Docker?

Comment: its looks you are missing `gcc` and\or `python-devel`?

Comment: The openssl dev libraries are missing install them with  `apk` or `apt`.

Comment: I'm using a base image where both are preloaded with the following lines: 
`RUN apt-get install -y git cmake build-essential curl libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev uuid-dev` and `RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils libboost-python-dev pkg-config valgrind`